# Accessing Lookup Values fails with Exception when the connected user is not the SharePoint Site Collection administrator

Tags: permissions, lookup-column, event-handlers

In sharepoint 2010 Foundation, after we installed a simple event receiver that mainly runs when certain items are added/modified, we noticed, during manual testing, that if we logged in as a user other than the sharepoint administrator account we would get an error whenever we tried retrieving to retrieve a simple lookup column information. The error Message said

```
Error loading and running event receiver      EvozonAdministrationEventReceivers.StartEmailNotification.StartEmailNotification in   EvozonAdministrationEventReceivers, 
Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=918ea4bf742b9a3a. Additional information is below.
: Value does not fall within the expected range.
```

The same code run on Dev or with the Administrator logged in had no issues running.

Does anybody have any idea why. The server has Active Directory installed. It makes absolutely no sense to me. Are lookups executed in some type of sandbox?

Partial code listing below:

```
var Field = FieldResolver.On(_onBoardingChecklist);
        SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(() =>
        {
            string computerType = LookupValue<Columns.ComputerType>();
 // .. omitted for previty

public string LookupValue<SITECOLUMN>() where SITECOLUMN : new()
    {
        if (_Field == null) 
            _Field = FieldResolver.On(_onBoardingChecklist);

        var value = (string)_onBoardingItem[_Field.For<SITECOLUMN>().InternalName];

        value = new SPFieldLookupValue(value).LookupValue;

        return value;
    }
```

Comment: Please add the omitted code inside your RWEP code to help solve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have a piece of code in your event receiver, which requires elevated privilegies.
You should use [SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivilegies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsecurity.runwithelevatedprivileges.aspx) for this piece of code.

**Update:**

Also, please make sure you have recreated all SharePoint objects *inside* the RunWithElevatedPrivilegies delegate, because, for example, this would work:

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(() =>
{
    using (SPSite site = new SPSite(properties.SiteId))
    {
        using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb(properties.RelativeWebUrl))
        {
            // ...
            web.Update();
        }
    }
});
```

But this, wouldn't:

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(() =>
{
    // ...
    properties.Web.Update();
});
```

**Thanks Anders Rask** for the important note about SPContext!

Comment: I'm already running with elevated privileges.

Comment: RunWithElevatedPrivilegies has some specifics. You should create all the SP objects inside it (starting from the SPSite), if you create them outside, this function does nothing. Could you place **all** of your receiver code into RunWithElevatedPrivilegies block, just for test?

Comment: you can't blindly run everything with elevated privileges because your tests fail when not logged in as an administrator.

Comment: Probably your list containing lookup values has unique permissions. You cannot use SPContext inside event receier though, you would need to use Properties inside RWEP:       SPSite site = new SPSite(properties.SiteId);
      SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb(properties.RelativeWebUrl);
      SPList list = web.Lists[properties.ListId];
      SPListItem item = list.Items.GetItemById(properties.ListItemId);

Comment: @Karthik Murugesan, agreed, that's why I wrote *just for test* :)

Comment: @Anders Rask, agreed again. I added the code just as an *abstract example* of how the RunWithElevatedPrivilegies method works (because we still can't examine most of the code which Mihai Lazar uses, and so I can't provide concrete code for him). Anyway, I think this is very important note, so I will fix my update. Thank you!

Comment: Hey guys thanks for the feedback. I don't have access to the server anymore since we've decided Sharepoint is a wrong technology for what we intended to develop. I was in fact getting access to list items etc from outside the RunWithElevated privileges, sounds kind of stupid, until you think about it a bit, that it would cause the headackes I had. But it might be it.